# Bulbs - Neo4J - Heroku Config Error?

Tags: python, heroku, neo4j, bulbs

I'm using [bulbs](http://bulbflow.com/overview/) to setup a Neo4J app on Heroku. Locally it runs fine, but when I deploy it on heroku, it raises the error part in the following code:

```
#heroku config:get NEO4J_URL
#http://user:password@instance.ip/
try:
    cfg = Config(instance.ip,user,password)
    g = Graph(cfg)
except: 
    return "OOPS! ERROR CONFIGURING GRAPH!"
```

What should I be doing?

I also tried the `cfg.set_neo4j_heroku()` but no use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of the latest versions, the Heroku Addon does not support sending Groovy scripts to the server for security reasons. Try Cypher instead? http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/cypher-query-lang.html